# To count number of pulses in avr between some elapsed time and display it

Tags: timer, hex, counter, avr, atmega16

I want to count the number of pulses that occurred between a delay of 'n' seconds in atmega32 using 16bit timer and store and display it.
`

```
TCNT1 = 0x0000;
TCCR1A = 0X00;
TCCR1B = 0X01;
_delay_ms(150);
TCCR1B = 0X00;
int K = TCNT1;
```

Is the above code correct for counting pulses?

Comment: What you did till now? Your Code?

Comment: I added the code which I have written for counting and storing number of pulses. Is the code correct?

Comment: Have you tried this code on the chip? Or do you not have access to one? The best way to learn something is to actually try it out :)